# Firebase filter where value is

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The following call:

```
fDB.ref(`organization/${uid}/attendance/${date}`)
.once('value')
.then(d => console.log(d.val()))
```

returns an object like so:

```
{ '-Lz8YxH_n7a5C6wv5vrX': 'absent',
  '-Lz8YxHbn5iOCxaGUBZt': 'absent',
  '-Lz8YxHfQPKH5BaIJBK_': 'absent',
  '-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn': 'present',
  '-Lz8YxHjtMUkroeyT5bv': 'absent',
  '-Lz8YxHmHqDblmBY4jyx': 'absent',
  '-Lz8YxHo-e4AiOwwex0s': 'absent',
  '-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO': 'present',
}
```

how can I query ONLY the values that are absent?
I tried:

```
fDB.ref(`organization/${uid}/attendance/`)
    .orderByChild(date)
    .equalTo('absent')
    .once('value')
    .then(d => console.log(d.val()))
```

The above returned null
I also tried

```
fDB.ref(`organization/${uid}/attendance/${date}`)
    .orderByKey()
    .equalTo('absent')
    .once('value')
    .then(d => console.log(d.val()))
```

Same thing null.  How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will filter out using `orderByValue` on the date node with `equalTo`, allowing you to run filter in values:

```
 fDB.ref(`organization/${uid}/attendance/${date}`)
    .orderByValue()
    .equalTo('absent')
    .once('value')
    .then(d => console.log(d.val()));
```